# BuildConfig.DEBUG remains true

Tags: android, eclipse

I've read the other questions about it here.
And I cleaned my source and set android:debuggable to false.
The only result is the warning, that I should not hardcode this.

And of course BuildConfig.DEBUG remains true!

Who knows really why and what to do?

Answer (score 6):

I've also seen reports of BuildConfig.DEBUG being unreliable, although I have not used it.

I have successfuly used:

```
    //Figure out if we are in debug mode or not
    boolean debugMode = (0 != (getApplicationInfo().flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_DEBUGGABLE));
```

Which reads the debuggable tag in AndroidManifest.xml.

Also, there is a Lint warning that goes further by saying, don't set that tag, android will figure it out for you.

Comment: Sorry, but I am not looking for an alterative way. I want a clean release build.

Comment: I verified that the android build automatically sets the debuggable tag if it does not exist. Because of this, there should not be a difference between the two methods. What else are you looking for?

Answer (score 0):

When you do a proper export of an apk, it should set it to false. Not sure if it matters if it is signed or not.